# mysqli not Fount in wamp

Tags: php, apache, xampp

Hola tengo instalado wamp pero al ejecutar un conexión no me function según dice no funciona mysqli

```
private function connectDB(){
    $this->link = new mysqli($this->host, $this->user, $this->pass, $this->dbname);
    if(!$this->link){
        $this->error ="Connection fail".$this->link->connect_error;
        return false;
    }
```

> Error
>
> ```
> Fatal error: Class 'mysqli' not found
> ```

Comment: ¿Tienes la extensión de MySQLi activada en WAMP?

Comment: ¿Y qué versión de PHP estás usando?

Comment: Hola, La Version es 5.6.19

Comment: @JosbertHernandez no respondiste la pregunta de Alvaro

Comment: Pues No lo se soy un poco nuevo, Como puedo verificar

Comment: Creo que debes agregar la extension Msqli en tu archivo php.ini **extension=php_mysqli.dll** hasta abajo

Comment: Resulta que esta insertada dicha extension

Comment: Ejecuta un phpinfo() para ver las extensiones cargadas